# gm convert: No decode delegate for this image format

Tags: graphicsmagick, gm

I am getting the below error on an AWS EC2 instance (I specifically say that as I don't have an issue with this on my Mac):

```
Error: Command failed: gm convert: No decode delegate for this image format (/tmp/5c5830319d29e4678e8691cd-1549705844271.jpg)
```

The file does exist just in case that looks to be the suspect.

My config for **gm** is as follows:

```
[mw-user@mwServer ~]$ gm version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.31 2018-11-17 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     no
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 no
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     no
  JPEG-2000                no
  JPEG                     no
  Little CMS               no
  Loadable Modules         no
  OpenMP                   yes (201511)
  PNG                      no
  TIFF                     no
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     no
  WMF                      no
  X11                      no
  XML                      no
  ZLIB                     yes

Host type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Configured using the command:
  ./configure

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = gcc
  CFLAGS   = -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread
  CPPFLAGS =
  CXX      = g++
  CXXFLAGS = -pthread
  LDFLAGS  =
  LIBS     = -lz -lm -lpthread
```

I am using the Node module:

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm("/tmp/5c5830319d29e4678e8691cd-1549705844271.jpg")
.resize(450, null)
.write("/tmp/5c5830319d29e4678e8691cd-1549705844271-Resized.jpg", (function(err){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}));
```

I don't know enough about gm to go anywhere from here. The problem seems like I don't have a "converter" for JPEG. Question is - how does one set this up so it supports most image formats like: jpg, png etc?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what OS your instance is running, but basically you don't seem to have `JPEG` support in **GraphicsMagick**.

So you need to work out what package manager your instance uses and then use that to install `libjpeg` and `libjpeg-dev` packages and then probably re-install **GraphicsMagick**.

Your comment seems to imply your question is broader than the JPEG-support you mention, but the answer is the same. You need to install

- libTIFF, libTIFF-dev
- libPNG, libPNG-dev
- ...

and then re-install **GraphicsMagick**.

Comment: Thanks! I am using AWS EC2 which uses yum. However, my question specifically is: "How does one set this up so it supports most image formats like: jpg, png etc?"

Comment: You, sir, are a legend! That did it! I have granted the bounty. Thanks so much - I can never repay you